# Export my mail database to ssd for read only

Tags: email, ssd, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I have a big database (40GB) of emails in thunderbird and I would like to get rid of this from my main email client so it runs faster.

I have to consult it once a day so it's still useful but it also slow my pc and the other things I do.

My idea was to take all the archive folder into another email client with the mailbox path set to a directory in a ssd. 
And I would also like to set to email client to read only so I cannot send message from this client.

Anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Email clients use different file types to archive emails. So the archived emails from thunderbird may not work on the new email client.

My advice is simply archiving the emails and move the folder to another location.

P.S. If you didn't add an account in email client, then it is impossible to send emails.